# Создание календаря. Проблема при выводе года в разных версиях IE.

Tags: jquery, javascript

JQUERY 1.7.1.

Для проекта появилась зада по созданию формы с календарем. выглядит она следующим образом:
[image]

> Возникла проблема в отработке скрипта
>   в разных версиях IE с 8-6. А в IE9,
>   Opera, Сhrom, Mozila - все работает
>   нормально. Суть проблемы: при выборе
>   даты на календаре, заполняется поле
>   "Когда". В разных версиях IE
>   отображение года разное. В IE9 - 2013
>   (правильный год), в IE в версиях с 8-6
>   показывает 3913год. Не могу понять как
>   можно исправить данную проблему.
>   Помогите разобраться.

Использовал следующие скрипты: 
 - `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`
 - `jquery.calendar.js`

код jquery.calendar.js:

```
(function($) { 

        function calendarWidget(el, params) { 

                var now   = new Date();
                var thismonth = now.getMonth();
                var thisyear  = now.getYear() + 1900;
                var thisdate = now.getDate();
                var thisday=now.getDay();
                if(thisday==0)thisday=7;
                var opts = {
                        days: 45
                };

                $.extend(opts, params);
                var days = parseInt(opts.days);
                var monthNames = [ 'янв', 'фев', 'мар', 'апр', 'май', 'июн', 'июл', 'авг', 'сен', 'окт', 'ноя', 'дек' ];
                var dayNames = [ 'пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс'];
                var table = '<div class="c_dn">';

            for (d=0; d<7; d++) {
                                table += '<div>' + dayNames[d] + '</div>';
                        }

            table += '</div><div class="c_wr"><table cellspacing="0">';


            table += '<tr class="newMonth" nmbtr="0" month="'+(thismonth+1)+'" year="'+thisyear+'">';

            if(thisday!=1){
            for (j=1;j<thisday;j++){
            table += '<td class="empty"></td>';
            }
            }
            var ch=thisdate;
            var m=thismonth;
            var y=thisyear;
            var nd=8-thisday;
            var newm=true;
            var rowspan=0;
            var newy='';
            var nmbtr=1;

            for (j=0;j<days;j++){
            if(ch<=getDaysInMonth(m,y)){
            table += '<td class="canclick" day="'+j+'"><div day="'+ch+'">'+ch+'</div></td>';
            ch++;
            nd--;
            }else{
            if(nd!=7)for (f=0;f<nd;f++){table += '<td class="empty"></td>';}
            ch=1;
            m++;
            if(m==12){m=0;y++;}
            table += '</tr><tr nmbtr="'+nmbtr+'" class="newMonth" month="'+(m+1)+'" year="'+y+'">';
            for (f=0;f<(7-nd);f++){table += '<td class="empty"></td>';}
            newm=true;
            nmbtr++;
            }
            if(nd==0){
            if (newm){
            rowspan=Math.ceil(((getDaysInMonth(m,y)-ch+1)+(7-nd))/7);
            if(y>thisyear)newy=' '+y;
            table += '<td class="month" rowspan="'+rowspan+'">'+monthNames[m]+newy+'</td>';newm=false;
            }
            if(ch<=getDaysInMonth(m,y)){table += '</tr><tr nmbtr="'+nmbtr+'" month="'+(m+1)+'" year="'+y+'">';nmbtr++;}

            nd=7;
            }


            if(j==(days-1)){
            for (f=0;f<nd;f++){table += '<td class="empty"></td>';}
            }
            }
            table += ('</tr></table></div>');

                el.html(table);
        }

        function getDaysInMonth(month,year)  {
        var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
        return daysInMonth;
        }


        // jQuery plugin initialisation
        $.fn.calendarWidget = function(params) {    
                calendarWidget(this, params);                
                return this; 
        }; 

})(jQuery); .....
```

Если заменить эту строку на:

```
var thisyear  = now.getYear() + 1900;
```

На эту:

```
var thisyear  = now.getYear();
```

Тогда в версиях IE с 8-6 правильно год показывает, но тогда в IE9 и в других браузерах показывает 113 год.

Как сделать так, чтобы год во всех версиях IE определялся верно?
Если необходимо выложить все файлы, то я выложу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [getFullYear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/29y2w2x3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

http://jsfiddle.net/9B9u5/

По поводу `getYear` сказано:

---

**Important**

This method is obsolete, and is provided for backward compatibility only. Use the getFullYear method instead.

In Internet Explorer 3.0, and then in Internet Explorer versions starting with Internet Explorer 9 standards mode, the value returned is the stored year minus 1900. For example, the year 1899 is returned as -1 and the year 2000 is returned as 100.

In Internet Explorer 4.0 through Internet Explorer 8 standards mode, the formula depends on the year. For the years 1900 through 1999, the value returned is a 2-digit value that is the stored year minus 1900. For dates outside that range, the 4-digit year is returned. For example, 1996 is returned as 96, but 1825 and 2025 are returned as is.

---

Comment: спасибо помогло:)